# Angular method for querySelectorAll and getElementsByTagName

Tags: angularjs

I am very new in Angular. I need a beginner's guide on the best way to define functions to get the length or count of tag (such as div) and Id/Class (#blah or .blah) via querySelectorAll and getElementsByTagName, so it can be called on html template and get current count of the particular elements on page.

```
function countTag(value1, value2) {
  var top_level_div = document.getElementById(' + value1 + ')
  top_level_div.document.getElementsByTagName(' + value2 + ’).length
}

function countElem(value) {
  document.querySelectorAll(' + value + ’).length
}
```

How to angularize the above 2 functions, so they can be call on html template anywhere inside the app? If directive may be a method to do so, can anyone help with a plnkr example?

Comment: When I started doing Angular I used to think it was some other entity than JavaScript.  It's not!  It's just more JavaScript.  You can use those regular JavaScript functions.  Your question is like "How do I add JavaScript to this JavaScript (Angular)?"  Just be careful of references and scope and it should be fine.

Comment: I never thought angular is another entity of js. Also, my question is far from "How to add js to js(angular)". My question is literally as above. How to angularize it so it can be called as "function(value)" on page. A very new beginner is also very literal, so dummy may well serve my know-how.

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery? When you import jQuery angular will automatically set angular.element (which is a reference to the library that angular will wrap dom objects with in certain situations) Sidenote: If you don't load jQuery angular will use a library that was made for angular called [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), which is a trimmed down version of jQuery.

Comment: Or are you asking how to wrap those functions to make them injectable?

Comment: BAM5, yes to your last question on how to make it injectable, cause Angular does not allow direct js command like this to interact with the Angular commands such as ng-hide etc. I presume making a directive using angular.element may be the way to do, yet I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If your're using a directive in your 'DDO' (Directive Definition Object) you have access to jQuery object as 'element' attribute (if jQuery is referenced before loading angular.js file).

In your link function (or compile.post method) just interact with element attribute.

Ex.

```
.directive('sampleDrv', function () {
  return {
    ...
    link: function (scope, element) { // + other attributes
        // Just use your jQuery logic/function provider in an example 
        // Only difference is now syntax ex. document == angular.element(document)

          function sampleFn() {
              var sampleElementText = angular.element(document).find('p').text();
              console.log(sampleElementText);
          }

          sampleFn();

    }
})
```

You also have $element object available on controller but it's not recommended to interact with element that way.

Also you may want to have a look at that brief explanation from Scott Allen - http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx

Also

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: This is just sample of directive, not exactly an example I can make sense to apply.